# Dictionary of instances of another Class 'cBeam ' as variable in an instance of Class 'cNode'

Tags: vba, class

When I execute the following sub, I instantiate the class cNode within which another set of class cBeam are instantiated. The instance of cBeam are stored in a dictionary `vBeamList` which are created within the `Private Sub Initialize()` section. I checked the values using `Debug.Print` and it works fine. However, when it enters `Public Property Get Beam(MemberNo As Long) As cBeam` it shows that `vBeamList(MemberNo)` is empty!

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dandelion As Object
    Dim NodeConnectivityDict As Object
    Dim NodeListDict As Object
    Set NodeListDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    '1. Creates dictionary of Nodes and connected beams | Node: [Node, b1,b2,b3, , ]
    Call SelectNodeConnection(dandelion)
    '2. Cleans the empty elements of beam array in #1 and adds end index as multiarray. | Node:[[b1,0],[b2,1],[b3,1]]
    Set NodeConnectivityDict = CleanNodeDictAndGetBeamConnectivity(dandelion)
    '3. Get the list of all beams connected to node and instantiate a class that shows the Node and beam with the
    'LC stored in them
    Call DevelopInstancesNodeBeamLC(NodeConnectivityDict, NodeListDict)


    Debug.Print NodeListDict(58).Beam(501).ID **<-When the error showsup**
End Sub

Sub DevelopInstancesNodeBeamLC(NodeConnectivityDict, NodeListDict)
    Dim nodeInstance As cNode
    For Each varKey In NodeConnectivityDict.keys():
        Set NodeListDict(varKey) = New cNode
        NodeListDict(varKey).Initialize varKey, NodeConnectivityDict(varKey)
    Next
End Sub
```

***Class cNode***

```
Private vID As Long
Private vBeamArray() As Variant
Private vNumBeams As Integer
Private vBeamList As Object


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set vBeamList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize(Node, BeamList)

    vID = Node
    vBeamArray = BeamList
    vNumBeams = UBound(vBeamArray) - LBound(vBeamArray) + 1

    For Each i In vBeamArray:
        vBeamList.Add i(0), New cBeam
        vBeamList(i(0)).Initialize i(0), i(1)
    Next

End Sub

Public Property Get ID() As Long
    ID = vID
End Property

Public Property Get NumberOfBeams() As Integer
    NumberOfBeams = vNumBeams
End Property

Public Property Get Beam(MemberNo As Long) As cBeam
    Set Beam = vBeamList(MemberNo)
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub
```

***Class cBeam***

```
Private vID As Long
Private vConnectivity As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize(BeamID, Connectivity)
    vID = BeamID
    vConnectivity = Connectivity
End Sub

Public Property Get ID() As Long
ID = vID
End Property

Public Property Get Connectivity() As Long
Connectivity = vConnectivity
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub
```

I have run out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing `Next i` in `Initialize`...

Comment: Sorry i missed that while cleaning the code. The error still persists 'Run-time error '424''.

Comment: Would help to show a small sub which reproduces the error  - it's not clear exactly how you're seeing this error and it's possible the problem is not in this code you posted.

Comment: `Debug.Print NodeListDict(58).Beam(501).ID` when this line is executed is when the error pops up.

Comment: When you do this: `vBeamList.Add i(0), New cBeam` is `i(0)` a Long-type, or is it possibly some other type such as string ?  `"501"` is not the same key as `501`

Comment: Its a long type.

Comment: That was my last guess.  Without running code to debug (which would need some input data) it's tricky to figure out what's the issue.

Comment: OK one more  - type of `varKey` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams What I observed from my debug is the dictionary key and items are successfully assigned in `Sub Initialize` of `cNode`. And then when calling `Property Get Beam`, the dictionary with the keys exist but the items are **empty**. No property, sub or function is called in between the two so to me the questions are why the instance of cbeam gets terminated on leaving `Sub Initialize`? Isnt `vBeamList` available to the whole class? Or does this have to do with some limitation of dictionaries, or with creating instances in other classes. I dont know if my observations assist in any way.

Comment: Can you simplify the calling code to make a runnable example which includes some actual data?   That's the only way I could possibly help I think.

Comment: Actually, the code connects to an API. Give me half an hour, I will simplify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this slightly modified version of your `Main` sub (and no other changes), I get the expected output.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim NodeConnectivityDict As Object
    Dim NodeListDict As Object

    Set NodeConnectivityDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set NodeListDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    NodeConnectivityDict.Add 33, Array(Array(10, 20), Array(30, 40), Array(50, 60))
    NodeConnectivityDict.Add 58, Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4), Array(501, 502))

    DevelopInstancesNodeBeamLC NodeConnectivityDict, NodeListDict

    Debug.Print NodeListDict(33).Beam(30).ID            '30
    Debug.Print NodeListDict(33).Beam(30).Connectivity  '40

    Debug.Print NodeListDict(58).Beam(501).ID           '501
    Debug.Print NodeListDict(58).Beam(501).Connectivity '502

End Sub
```

Comment: Its extremely bad of me, I realized that the index I was inputting `Debug.Print NodeListDict(58).Beam(501).ID` should have been `Debug.Print NodeListDict(58).Beam(505).ID` . I apologize for taking your time and effort.

Comment: Again Tim thank you for your help and I am extremely sorry to take your precious time. I have a deadline for this job and I am stumbling a lot but definitely getting there.